# simple memory sharing issue

Tags: linux, memory, posix, shared-memory

I'm trying to simulate simple shared memory between two processeses on ubuntu. here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main() {

pid_t pid = fork();

if (pid == 0) {     //Child
        int shm_fd = shm_open("JSHM", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
        ftruncate(shm_fd, 4096);
        void *ptr = mmap(0, 4096, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
        sprintf(ptr, "Jani");
        printf("%i descriptor from child\n", shm_fd);
        printf("%p ptr from child\n\n", ptr);
}
if (pid > 0) {      //Parent
        sleep(5);
        int shm_fd = shm_open("JSHM", O_RDONLY, 0666);
        printf("%i descriptor from parent\n", shm_fd);
        void *ptr = mmap(0, 4096, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
        //printf("%s", (char *)ptr);
        printf("%p ptr from parent\n", ptr);
}

}
```

And the output:

3 descriptor from child

0xb7750000 ptr from child

3 descriptor from parent

0xffffffff ptr from parent

why doesn't second mmap (from parent) work?

Thanks.

Comment: `PROT_WRITE` for an `O_RDONLY` file descriptor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a slight error in your requested access permissions. In the parent section, you're passing `O_RDONLY` to `shm_open()` but then you're trying to `mmap()` it with `PROT_WRITE` which is not allowed.